# Text Game allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was wondering if 'text' games are allowed in any form on Physics SE.

For example:

POSTER describes a physicist

LOOP:

> 1 -> $n$ people guess. $n_i$ gets it right
>
> $n_i$ describes a physicist

Thought it would be a nice/fun way to learn about new physicists besides just reading.

Answer (score 8):

I'd say no.

My feeling is that we are building a catalog of answered questions about physics: a resource for future visitors.

The kind of game you are suggesting would be a good fit for chat.